# C - Flush file buffer on forced termination

Tags: c, file, signals

I use fwrite to write the log of my program into a file. It happens that if my program receive a **SIG_KILL** the buffer won´t be flushed and some data will be lost. Is there any way to force the flush of the buffer when the program is forced to finish?

If there is no solution do you guys think it is a good ideia to use fflush() after I have one completed line of information in the buffer? This way I would just lose a line of information at the worst scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't force the user to use `SIGKILL` to terminate your program? It's usually supposed to be a last resort if the program is so wedged it can't be otherwise terminated which is why it *cannot* be blocked or handled.

Comment: I don´t force it. But imagine that someone remebers to use Ctrl+ALt+Del and shut down the process, in cases like this I can´t allow the user to lose all the information in the buffer...

Comment: No. If the user decides to `SIGKILL` the program unnecessarily, it's *the user's own fault*. If you make your program ignore all other signals, it's *your fault*

Comment: What does Ctrl+Alt+Del? To SIGKILL a process, you Ctrl-C.

Comment: @Olaf I can handle the signal from the Ctrl-C but I can´t handle the SIG_KILL from the task manager.

Comment: What is **the** task manager?

Comment: Ctrl-C is SIGINT, not SIGKILL.

Comment: No program gets a second chance with SIGKILL; it is fatal and the process is not allowed to do anything about it (no cleanup of unflushed buffers, in particular).  Use SIGTERM or SIGHUP; you can set signal handlers for those.  But if you need the data written to file, look at the various O_SYNC, O_DSYNC, etc options for [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), or use `fflush()` to ensure that data is sent to disk for each line or other relevant unit of output.  You have few reasonable alternatives.

Comment: @Olaf: I think the OP must be using Microsoft Windows but has forgotten to add a suitable tag.

Answer (score 0):

If your process gets a true `SIGKILL`, there is nothing your process can do as it will be immediately killed by the OS.

Per [the POSIX standard on signals](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04):

> ...
>
> While a process is stopped, any additional signals that are sent to
>   the process shall not be delivered until the process is continued,
>   **except SIGKILL which always terminates the receiving process**.
>
> ...
>
> The system shall not allow the action for the signals SIGKILL or
>   SIGSTOP to be set to SIG_IGN.
>
> ...
>
> The system shall not allow a process to catch the signals SIGKILL and
>   SIGSTOP.

You can't catch `SIGKILL`, and you can't ignore it.